# DataTable not being refreshed in Primefaces 6.0

Tags: primefaces

I have a Primefaces 6.0 DataTable as this:

```
 <h:outputText value="There are #{jsfbean.myList.size()} items in the list " />
               <h:form>
                   <p:commandButton  update="tbl"  value="Refresh Data" />
                   <p:dataTable id="tbl" var="list" value="#{jsfbean.myList}"  

                         paginator="true"
                         rows="40"
                         >
```

When I load the page the output text says "there are 500 items in the list"

Then I add a record in another page, go back to this grid and the output text says  "there are 501 items in the list"

The new item is not shown in the table, I use the Refresh button and the grid still not refreshed

Any idea?

Comment: mmmmm i see the problem, just give an id for your form after that use it to update your dataTable example `update = :idForm:tbl`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not shown"? You have 40 rows per page. Do you expect the new item to show up on the first page, or did you check the last, 13th, page? Can you see that there are 21 items on 13th page?